# I need help; the Solidity Code yields a warning you will see below

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas, contract-debugging

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4; 

 contract token { function mintToken(address receiver, uint amount){if 
      (msg.value < amount)
        throw;

    if (msg.value > amount)
         throw;  } }
    contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public deadline;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward; 
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;
    event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    function Crowdsale(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 10000 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 20160 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 0.1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function buy() public payable {
        if(!crowdsaleClosed)
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.mintToken(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /**
     * Check if goal was reached
     *
     * Checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign
     */
    function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    /**
     * Withdraw the funds
     *
     * Checks to see if goal or time limit has been reached, and if so, and the funding goal was reached,
     * sends the entire amount to the beneficiary. If goal was not reached, each contributor can withdraw
     * the amount they contributed.
     */
    function safeWithdrawal() afterDeadline {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a compiler warning that you are "safe to ignore". As per the warning definition:

> If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas
>   limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or
>   actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or
>   copying arrays in storage)

The code itself doesn't seem to be looping through or copying any arrays, but the warning also appears when using send() or transfer().

Comment: indeed but i'm stuck there, can't create the contract. I'm using REMIX as the IDE.

Comment: If you can't create the contract it is not due to this warning... What error are you getting when trying to deploy it? What's the complete code?

Comment: Please update the question with the complete code as you can't format code on the comments.

Comment: I have the same issue when <adress>.transfer(amount); . It looks like not really so bad as transfering funds is a must, but Remix doesn't allow to "Create" the contract, as the funcion containing "transfer" has an infinite gas cost...

Comment: I will remove that and see how it goes.